# How is it called the feature of persisting process images in OSX?

Tags: macos, process, osx-lion, osx-mavericks, reboot

How do you call the feature of OSX being able to restart, but persisting each process state, in a way that after restating is finished it can restore each one of these processes exactly how they where previously?

For example a movie would still be paying in the same part, a text document would still have half of the sentence written even if I didn't save the txt file to disk, the browser would still have the same tabs opened and the same amount of scroll done, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

People call it in many different ways but "Application persistence" and "State Restoration" seem to be the most "official" ones.